# Using case statement to get weekly count of total orders, cancelled orders and % of cancelled orders

Tags: sql, case

first time poster and just looking for some guidance on writing a case statement. I'd like to pull the following from a single table

**total orders by week 
cancelled orders by week 
% of orders cancelled**

I did some reading on case statements, but couldn't find exactly what I was looking for. I assume the case statement would be something along the lines of

"case when order = 'cancelled' THEN count orders", but I also know that's wrong, so just looking for some assistance.

Thanks in advance!

-ET

Comment: Can you _edit_ your post and add sample data and expected results? Also, could you tag your question specifying which DBMS you're using. That would help us give you a better answer for your question

Comment: Sample data, desired results and an appropriate database tag would all be very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

The usual ways of doing a count of partial rows is to do a `count` query with a where clause to select which rows. Each of these can be outer joined with other similar queries.

The way to do it in one select using `case` is to put the `case` inside a `sum`:

```
SELECT SUM(case when order = 'cancelled' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS cancelled, ...
```

Answer (score 0):

You should probably build a nested query for this:
First, build you query to get things sorted by week.

```
SELECT orderID, orderStatus, DATEPART(week, orderDate) as orderWeek
FROM orders
```

Then you can probably get a select from that as follows:

```
SELECT count(orderID) OVER(PARTITION BY orderWeek) AS Total
,count(orderID) OVER(PARTITION BY orderWeek, orderStatus) AS CountPerStatus
,orderWeek
FROM (SELECT orderID, orderStatus, DATEPART(week, orderDate) as orderWeek
FROM orders) a
```

add then finally get your totals on one row:

```
SELECT Total, CountPerStatus, orderWeek
FROM (
    SELECT count(orderID) OVER(PARTITION BY orderWeek) AS Total
    ,count(orderID) OVER(PARTITION BY orderWeek, orderStatus) AS CountPerStatus
    ,orderWeek
    FROM (
        SELECT orderID, orderStatus, DATEPART(week, orderDate) as orderWeek
        FROM orders
) a
) b
WHERE CountPerStatus = 'Cancelled'
```

This can clearly be simplified but I prefer to explicit it for better understanding. Hope it helps.