# Reducing four MySQL queries to one

Tags: mysql

I'm running four statements to see how many appointments are passed due, due today, due this week or any records that don't have appointments (unused).

I have two tables, one for records (contacts) and another for the appointments (appointments) in a single to many relationship. Each contact is unique in the [contacts] table but can have multiple records in the [appointments] table (to maintain history) and the highest appointments.id is the most recent appointment for the contact.

So, currently I have:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS "Late" FROM contacts c JOIN (SELECT MAX(id) max_id, contact_id FROM appointments GROUP BY contact_id) c_max ON (c_max.contact_id = c.id) JOIN appointments a on (a.id = c_max.max_id) WHERE c.active = 1 AND a.appointment < CURDATE()

SELECT COUNT(*) AS "Today" FROM contacts c JOIN (SELECT MAX(id) max_id, contact_id FROM appointments GROUP BY contact_id) c_max ON (c_max.contact_id = c.id) JOIN appointments a on (a.id = c_max.max_id) WHERE c.active = 1 AND DATE_FORMAT(a.appointment, "%Y-%m-%d") = DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), "%Y-%m-%d")

SELECT COUNT(*) AS "This Week" FROM contacts c JOIN (SELECT MAX(id) max_id, contact_id FROM appointments GROUP BY contact_id) c_max ON (c_max.contact_id = c.id) JOIN appointments a on (a.id = c_max.max_id) WHERE c.active = 1 AND a.appointment > CURDATE() + INTERVAL 1 DAY AND a.appointment < CURDATE() + INTERVAL 7 DAY

SELECT COUNT(*) AS "Unused" FROM contacts WHERE active = 1 AND id NOT IN (SELECT contact_id FROM appointments)
```

And these work fine, but I thought I might try and squeeze them in to one query to run faster (?) and this is where I come unstuck, I tried many variations of:

```
SELECT 
    CASE 
        WHEN a.appointment < CURDATE() THEN "Late" 
        WHEN DATE_FORMAT(a.appointment, "%Y-%m-%d") = DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), "%Y-%m-%d") THEN "Today" 
        WHEN a.appointment > CURDATE() + INTERVAL 1 DAY AND a.appointment < CURDATE() + INTERVAL 7 DAY THEN "This Week" 
        WHEN c.id NOT IN (SELECT contact_id FROM appointments) THEN "Unused" 
        ELSE "Error"
    END AS "Status", 
    COUNT(a.appointment) AS "Count"
FROM contacts c JOIN (SELECT MAX(id) max_id, contact_id FROM appointments GROUP BY contact_id) c_max ON (c_max.contact_id = c.id) JOIN appointments a on (a.id = c_max.max_id) WHERE c.active = 1
```

---

[edit]
Thanks to [Kamikaze](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59537380/11596915) I've adjusted to this that get's the first three queries to work, just struggling to get the last one (returns zero, rather than the actual count):

```
SELECT 
    SUM(CASE WHEN a.appointment < CURDATE() THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS "Late",
    SUM(CASE WHEN DATE_FORMAT(a.appointment, "%Y-%m-%d") = DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), "%Y-%m-%d") THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS "Today",
    SUM(CASE WHEN a.appointment > CURDATE() + INTERVAL 1 DAY AND a.appointment < CURDATE() + INTERVAL 7 DAY THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS "This Week",
    SUM(CASE WHEN c.id NOT IN (SELECT contact_id FROM appointments) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS "Unused"
FROM contacts c JOIN (SELECT MAX(id) max_id, contact_id FROM appointments GROUP BY contact_id) c_max ON (c_max.contact_id = c.id) JOIN appointments a on (a.id = c_max.max_id) WHERE c.active = 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just happened to answer a [very similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59535043/using-case-statement-to-get-weekly-count-of-total-orders-cancelled-orders-and/59535704#59535704):

The answer is to use a SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN ... END) as col1, SUM(CASE WHEN ... END) as col2, etc where each `CASE` returns 1 or 0.

Comment: If there's a very similar question, just close as a duplicate, don't bother posting an answer.

Comment: The answer is similar but the questions not so much.

Comment: Thank you, that's a really helpful and get's me three quarters of the way - quite literally, first three queries work, last one doesn't which I think might be to do with the join but not sure how to fix it

Comment: Ahh, nevermind, I just realised I can reference that in another way, thanks for your help, all sorted